# What is the easiest way to convert an Excel spreadsheet with tabular data to JSON?

Tags: json, spreadsheet, xls, file-conversion

I want to convert spreadsheet data from Excel or Open Office saved as *.xls to *.json

- Data is not sensitive
- File is not very large

Comment: Found this macro, not yet tested: https://gist.github.com/aaronhoogstraten/49b9c0f5e4ac705ebe51

Comment: There's also this: http://thdoan.github.io/mr-data-converter/

Comment: try this free app from windows store https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/excel-into-json/9p3b2s2k2qhb

Comment: Mr. Data Converter. https://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/

Comment: There's a simple way which involves no tools other than Excel. Use a formula to output JSON objects like so: `="{ ""thingA"":""" & A2 & """, ""thingB"":" & B2 & """ }, "`. This will output your JSON object rows which you can copy and paste inside `[ ]` to get your JSON array. e.g. if the A2 value is `cat` and the B2 value is `dog` you would get: `{ "thingA":"dog", "thingB":cat" }, ` for this row. Drag the row down to fill out the spreadsheet. Double `""` will escape the single `"` character. Because it's a formula you can be selective about what you include and name properties as well.

Comment: Why is this question closed?

Comment: Slight improvement to Aaron's formula, uses first row headers as property names / keys:  `="{ """&A$1&""":""" & A2 & """, """&B$1&""":""" & B2 & """ }, "`

Comment: I am not sure why this question is closed, my first search brought me to this question and it is exactly what I was looking.

Comment: https://transform-x.dev/excel-to-json is a web ui that can do this.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Assuming you really mean *easiest* and are not necessarily looking for a way to do this programmatically, you can do this:

1. Add, if not already there, a row of "column Musicians" to the spreadsheet. That is, if you have data in columns such as:

   ```
   Rory Gallagher      Guitar
   Gerry McAvoy        Bass
   Rod de'Ath          Drums
   Lou Martin          Keyboards
   Donkey Kong Sioux   Self-Appointed Semi-official Stomper
   ```

   **Note**: you might want to add "Musician" and "Instrument" in row 0 (you might have to insert a row there)
2. Save the file as a CSV file.
3. Copy the contents of the CSV file to the clipboard
4. Go to http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm
5. Verify that the "First row is column names" checkbox is checked
6. Paste the CSV data into the content area
7. Mash the "Convert CSV to JSON" button

   With the data shown above, you will now have:

   ```
   [
     {
       "MUSICIAN":"Rory Gallagher",
       "INSTRUMENT":"Guitar"
     },
     {
       "MUSICIAN":"Gerry McAvoy",
       "INSTRUMENT":"Bass"
     },
     {
       "MUSICIAN":"Rod D'Ath",
       "INSTRUMENT":"Drums"
     },
     {
       "MUSICIAN":"Lou Martin",
       "INSTRUMENT":"Keyboards"
     }
     {
       "MUSICIAN":"Donkey Kong Sioux",
       "INSTRUMENT":"Self-Appointed Semi-Official Stomper"
     }
   ]
   ```

   With this simple/minimalistic data, it's probably not required, but with large sets of data, it can save you time and headache in the proverbial long run by checking this data for aberrations and abnormalcy.
8. Go here: http://jsonlint.com/
9. Paste the JSON into the content area
10. Pres the "Validate" button.

If the JSON is good, you will see a "Valid JSON" remark in the Results section below; if not, it will tell you where the problem[s] lie so that you can fix it/them.

Comment: Converting with a web page is not useful for excessive data

Comment: Doesn't really work if you want to create a property with an array of items. such as having multiple instruments.

Comment: I found the answer to converting large amounts of data online, for free:  Upload your files to your Google Drive, to make it a Google Sheets document.  Then follow this blog post from Pamela Fox http://blog.pamelafox.org/2013/06/exporting-google-spreadsheet-as-json.html

Comment: I use http://www.csvjson.com/csv2json. Easy to convert from CSV to JSON

Comment: If you have UTF-8 encoded data, exporting to CSV from Excel will mess them up. I prefer to just copy the data from Excel, paste them in a decent editor (vscode, sublime text, notepad++) and use regular expressions to convert them to JSON.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65186806/6499726